# Shift the value of the variable in R "A" instead of NA

Tags: r, dataframe, na

I need to put the value of variable "A" in place of the NA of variable "B".
Example of my dataframe:

```
> df <- data.frame(A = seq(1, 10), B = c(1, NA, 3, 4, NA, NA, 7, 8, NA, NA))
> df
    A  B
1   1  1
2   2 NA
3   3  3
4   4  4
5   5 NA
6   6 NA
7   7  7
8   8  8
9   9 NA
10 10 NA
```

I want the above dataframe converted into this:

```
> df
    A  B
1   1  1
2   2  2
3   3  3
4   4  4
5   5  5
6   6  6
7   7  7
8   8  8
9   9  9
10 10 10
```

Answer (score 2):

Using R base indexing

```
> df$B[is.na(df$B)] <- df$A[is.na(df$B)]
> df
    A  B
1   1  1
2   2  2
3   3  3
4   4  4
5   5  5
6   6  6
7   7  7
8   8  8
9   9  9
10 10 10
```

Comment: Thank you very much! it also worked quite well this way.

Answer (score 2):

Use `coalesce`

```
library(dplyr)
df <- df %>%
     mutate(B = coalesce(B, A))
```

-output

```
df
 A  B
1   1  1
2   2  2
3   3  3
4   4  4
5   5  5
6   6  6
7   7  7
8   8  8
9   9  9
10 10 10
```

Answer (score 2):

I prefer `coalesce`. Here is one with an `ifelse`:

```
library(dplyr)
df %>% 
  mutate(B = ifelse(is.na(B), A, B))
```

```
   A  B
1   1  1
2   2  2
3   3  3
4   4  4
5   5  5
6   6  6
7   7  7
8   8  8
9   9  9
10 10 10
```